# Access Property of class in parent namespace

Tags: php

I have two class, main class is app.php in root directory, and db.php in \system
How To Get property $config in class base, with namespace pattern??
I want to get $config in class base, this is what I want

I define config for hostname,user,pass
then I declare base class wit new \App\base
I can get config in class db

```
<?php
// \App.php
namespace App;
class base{
    private $config;
    private $db;
    function __construct($config){
      $this->config = $config;
      $this->db = new \App\system\db;
    }
    public function getTest() {
        return $this->test;
    }
}

function load($namespace) {
    $splitpath = explode('\\', $namespace);
    $path      = '';
    $name      = '';
    $firstword = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($splitpath); $i++) {
        if ($splitpath[$i] && !$firstword) {
            if ($i == count($splitpath) - 1) {
                $name = $splitpath[$i];
            } else {

                $path .= DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $splitpath[$i];
            }
        }

        if ($splitpath[$i] && $firstword) {
            if ($splitpath[$i] != __NAMESPACE__) {
                break;
            }

            $firstword = false;
        }
    }
    if (!$firstword) {
        $fullpath = __DIR__ . $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $name . '.php';
        return include_once ($fullpath);
    }
    return false;
}

function loadPath($absPath) {
    return include_once ($absPath);
}
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ . '\load');
?>

<?php
// \System\db.php
namespace App\system;
class db{
    private $config;
    function __construct(){
        $this->config = "How To Get property $config in class base, with namespace pattern??";
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do? There is no "namespace pattern". Maybe you have not understood what namespaces are for. Read the php doc about them.

Comment: In your db.php you need type `use App\base;` and then in class `$this->base = new base; $basetest = $this->base->getTest()`, but of course base class must be loaded (require).

Comment: i just update full of code, please help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you something like this:

```
class db{
  private $test;
  function __construct(){
    include('../app.php');
    $app = new base();
    $this->test = $app->getTest();
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just pass the config when you create the db object. Also use the `use` keyword for better readability.

**\App**

```
namespace App;

use \App\system\db;

class base {
    private $config;
    private $db;
    function __construct($config){
      $this->config = $config;
      $this->db = new db($config);
    }
    public function getTest() {
        return $this->test;
    }
}
```

**\System\db.php**

```
namespace App\system;

class db {
    private $config;
    function __construct($config){
        $this->config = $config;
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, well I already use this way, I need to do it without passing paramater, so it can be dinamically called in other class like db which need config array